# download multiple files from page and send the archive to user javascript

Tags: javascript

On the page there are several links that you can download multiple files (with a third-party api).

Is there any way to make sure that the user by pressing the button to download and choose where to save started to download them all at once and in a single zip file or simply in one directory?

The server in my case only gives a list of URLs where the files are. The challenge for the client to upload and merge them into the archive, and give it to the user.

I found [Download multiple files from remote server with a single user confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459682/download-multiple-files-from-remote-server-with-a-single-user-confirmation?rq=1) helpful, but...

Is this possible to do only with javascript without flash and etc...?

Comment: are all the resources on your server?

Comment: no, they on the third-party server

Comment: then you can't use javascript to build a zip file for the user...